# all of my textures in an array are the same

Tags: java, arrays, opengl, lwjgl

so I'm making an array of textures to reference so i can use them from outside of my render loop, but all of the images are the same inside of the array.

```
Texture[] loadTextures(){
        //Loading Textures
        Texture[] textures = new Texture[56];

        for (int ii = 0; ii < 56; ii++) {
            System.out.println(ii);
            try {
    //*//       textures[ii] = TextureLoader.getTexture("png",
                     new FileInputStream(new File("res/Cards/"+ii+".png")));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Display.destroy();
                System.exit(1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Display.destroy();
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
        return textures;
    }
```

please tell me if you need the rest of my code, I suspect the problem lies with line *.

// a record of me looking for my own answers//

**VOID** --Possible solution// I've been looking at the opengl documentation and there is something called **ARRAY TEXTURE** to be called when binding the textures but I don't understand most of the terms in the documentation.
(this page laid it out clear for me: [more documentation (in english)](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_array.txt))

Answer (score 0):

I have done the following in my game.

-I put a "quickLoader" method in my game.

code:

```
    public static Texture quickLoad(String name){
    Texture tex = null;
    tex = loadTexture("res/img/" + name + ".png", "PNG");
    return tex;
}
```

loadTexture method:

```
    public static Texture loadTexture(String path, String fileType){
    Texture tex = null;
    InputStream in = ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(path);
    try {
        tex = TextureLoader.getTexture(fileType, in);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return tex;
}
```

created an enum to store all types of textures (tiles)

```
public enum TileType {

stone("stone", true),
dirt("dirt", false);

public String textureName;
boolean solid;

TileType(String textureName, boolean solid){
    this.textureName = textureName;
    this.solid = solid;
}

}
```

the first text in brackets is the file name of the image.

```
stone("stone", true),
```

"stone" is the name of the file.

then I used a "tile" class to do all the positioning, texturing and drawing.

```
    private float x, y, width, height;
private Texture texture;
private TileType type;

public Tile(float x, float y, float width, float height, TileType tile){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.texture = quickLoad(tile.textureName);
    this.type = tile;
}

public void draw(){
    drawQuadTex(texture, x, y, width, height);
}
```

drawQuadTex method:

```
    public static void drawQuadTex(Texture tex, float x, float y, float quadWidth, float quadHeight){
    tex.bind();
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);


    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    glVertex2f(0, 0);

    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    glVertex2f(quadWidth, 0);

    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    glVertex2f(quadWidth, quadHeight);

    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glVertex2f(0, quadHeight);

    glEnd();
    glLoadIdentity();

}
```

so now we have a good base to handle textured tiles. now for the array.

```
    public TileChanger(GridHandler grid){
    this.grid = grid;
    this.types = new TileType[2];
    this.types[0] = TileType.stone;
    this.types[1] = TileType.dirt;
    this.index = 0;
}
```

keep in mind you will have to adjust some values here and there.

you could come up with something to make them draw on the screen, but I use them in a double int array called "map" (map[][]) and use the numbers from the array list to make a map, so I can't really help you with that.

I hope this helped, or at least got you one step closer.

edit: Oops this post is 1 year old...